# OpenAPI as a single source of truth - limitations

Tags: rest, architecture, openapi, openapi-generator, system-design

One of the benefits being promoted for API-first design or OpenAPI is that of their use as a single source of truth. To my mind, these schemas only serve as a contract - the actual source of truth for your API lies in your microservices implementation (typically a http endpoint).

How can OpenAPI claim to be a single source of truth when the contract cannot be enforced until the implementation on the API side is complete? I realise there is tooling available to assist with this, such as validation middleware that can be used to match your request and response against your schema, however this is typically only validated at the point that a network request is made, not at compile time.

Of course you could write api tests to validate, but this is very much dependent on good test coverage and not something you get out of the box.

TLDR - OpenAPI markets itself as being a single source of truth for APIs, but this simply isn't true until your API implementation matches the spec. What tools/techniques (if any) can be used to mitigate this?

Answer (score 0):

Did a bit of additional research into available tooling and found a solution that helps mitigate this issue:

[open-api-backend](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openapi-backend) (and presumably other such libraries) have capabilities to map your api routes/handlers to a specific openAPI operation or operationID. You can then enforce schema validation such that only routes defined in the spec can be implemented, else a fail-fast error is thrown)